# Spark-scala, defining a custom filename convention

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have files in a directory and they have the same naming convention. It looks like this:

```
id_timestamp_name_someint.txt
```

For example:

```
100_20180709010203_FIRST_3432.txt
```

With 20180709010203 being, year 2018, 07 month, 09 day, 01 hour, 02 minutes, 03 sec.

I list the filenames in this directory like this:

```
def getListOfFiles(dir: String): List[String] = {
  val file = new File(dir)
  file.listFiles.filter(_.isFile).sortBy(_.lastModified).map(_.getName).toList 
}
```

Now I need to define the naming convention on spark-scala, so spark can recognize on which position is the id, the timestamp and the name. Because I want to compare the files with their id and then with the timestamp. Does anybody has an idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you add some more info on what you trying to achieve (not sure what you mean by compare here)? Do you want to load different groups of files into spark depending on the id/timestamp/name?

Comment: I want to compare the IDs. If they are the same, then I want to compare the timestamp. And if the date is 'later' as the previous - that means I have to compare the content and If there are a new records, I have to add these, so to update the table.

But first I have to define the naming convention, so a general one. (the first position is the ID, the second timestamp etc.)

Comment: It sounds like you could split on "_" and then use a case class to speparate the files names into id, timestamp and so on. Would that help?

Comment: That is all I know so far too. I can't structure my code.
Split is clear.. and then I have to say that the first piece is the ID, the second - timestamp and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define some logic on the names of some files contained in a directory, you can use `wholeTextFiles`, that returns a RDD of tuples that associates files names to their content.

In your case, you could do something like :

```
case class FileName(id : Int, ts : String, name : String, value : Int)
val rdd : RDD[(FileName, String)] = sc
  .wholeTextFiles("hdfs:///tmp/files")
  .map{ case(path, content) => 
      path.replaceAll(".txt$", "").split("/").last.split("_") -> content }
  /* the logic here is to first remove ".txt", then get rid of the path
     and finally splitting on '_' to separate your 4 fields. */
  .map{ case (Array(id, ts, name, value), content) => 
      FileName(id.toInt, ts, name, value.toInt) -> content}
```

Then you could apply any logic you like on `rdd`, using `reduceByKey` for instance to keep the records you are interested in.

For instance, let's say that for each id and name, you want to keep the record having the latest timestamp. You could do it like this:

```
rdd
    .map{ case(fn, content) => (fn.id, fn.name) -> (fn.ts, fn.value, content) }
    .reduceByKey((a, b) => if(a._1 >= b._1) a else b)
```

Comment: Can you give me some example with reduceByKey, because I that is actually my problem? I can't structure my coce to achieve this.

Comment: I added an example using reduceByKey. If that does not help you, try editing your question to add more details on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: case class FileName(id : Int, ts : String, name : String, value : Int)
that was a good hint! I want just to say now that the first piece of my filename (till the first _) is the id, the second piece is the timestamp, the third is the name.
So in the example:
100_20180709010203_FIRST_3432.txt
spark should recognize that the 100 is the id (till the first _) them comes the timestamp, then the name and then the value.

So with the getListOfFiles - I already can list all filenames in the directory, I just want to define these now as I explained above.